# Why my nvidia driver is not working on my laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia-settings

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 TLS.I install the nvidia from the ppa.But after I reboot,I still using the Intel graphics driver I have put the noueavus into the black list.BTW there is no nvidia section in the additional drivers in the sittings.How can I switch my video drivers into nvidia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x-server (usally Xorg) wouldn't use an Intel driver if it wasn't trying to use an Intel GPU. I guess you have hybrid graphics so you should read up on the topic in Ubuntu wiki.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics